# Using FileInputStream, Scanner, next(), and useDelimiter read multi-line .txt files

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter

I have a text file that contains:

```
griffin.keyes   108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet soup" zookeeper
rosario.dawson  3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "animal doctor" admin
bernie.gorilla  a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret password"   veterinarian
donald.monkey   17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    "M0nk3y business"   zookeeper
jerome.grizzlybear  3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    "grizzly1234"   veterinarian
bruce.grizzlybear   0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    "letmein"   admin
```

I am reading it into a two-dimensional array using this code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Credentials {
    private FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
    private Scanner inFS = null;                   // Scanner object
    final private String [][] credArray = new String[6][4];        

    public String[][] credArray() throws IOException {
        int i = 0;                                 // Index variable
        int j = 0;                                 // Index variable

        // Import credentials data.
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("credentials.txt");
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        // Use carriage return and tab as token separators
        inFS.useDelimiter("[\\r\\t]");

        // Create array of credentials.txt
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j) {
                credArray[i][j] = inFS.next();
            }
        }
        fileByteStream.close(); //Closes file.
        return credArray;
    } 
}
```

The first line is read it without issue. Lines 2-6 are near in with the first String having `\n` added to the front of it. For example: `\nrosario.dawson`.

I suspect an issue with the delimiter, but I'm not sure what else to use. I tried using `("[\\r\\n\\t]")` but that just offsets everything after the first line with a `""` for per line. How would I go about correcting this?

Comment: Any chance this is *actually* a tab-separated file? There's libraries for reading those and handling quoted columns.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the 4 columns are separated by 3 tabs, and after each row, there's a carriage return. Also, unfortunately, I am only allowed to use the code options listed in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my own question.

The issue lied with this section of code:

```
// Create array of credentials.txt
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j) {
            credArray[i][j] = inFS.next();
        }
    }
```

I needed to correct the way the way I was reading the information from the scanner, `inFS`, into the array, `credArray`. I did it by changing the code to:

```
// Create array of credentials.txt
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j) {
            credArray[i][j] = inFS.next().replaceAll("\\n", "");
        }
    }
```

This automatically erases any new-line code entries for lines 2-6.